# Nexus Sonatype - Getting NugetAPI Key through API/CLI?

Tags: nuget, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

Is there a way through the API or CLI I can retrieve that newly created uses API key?

I have used an Ansible Role to setup/configure Nexus Sonatype.

https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss#example-playbook

I re-run the role everytime i need a new repository, and it also creates a new user that has full access to that new repository.

I am trying to fully provision nexus via ansible, so I am trying not to take a pause, manually login to Nexus, and grab the API key from the GUI if possible, and update my ansible playbook.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at this time via APIs provided by Nexus Repository (3).  See https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-25154 for more information.